# What Font does Notepad use to display e.g. Hebrew, when it claims to use Lucida Console but Lucida Console doesn't have those characters?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, unicode, notepad

Courier New has the character \u05D0  hebrew letter aleph

some other fonts do too such as Miriam and David.

[image]

I can paste that into notepad

Lucida Console does not have the character. Character map shows that Lucida Console doesn't have the character.

Yet notepad displays it even when Lucida Console font is set

[image]

So what Font is notepad using?

Comment: Notepad uses Lucida Console from Windows 2000 to Windows 8.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Lucida console doesn't have the aleph character either. I've just amended the question to use Lucida Console as the example instead of Consolas, but same issue

Comment: If I try in word then it changes from lucida console to arial, so it's possible notepad is doing that and not saying so, though when I choose arial it moves a bit so maybe notepad's not using arial when lucida is chosen, so it's still not clear what it's using

Comment: Check  value(s) `PlaneX` (where `X` could vary from `1` to `16`) of next registry keys: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\LanguagePack\SurrogateFallback` and/or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\LanguagePack\SurrogateFallback`.

Comment: @JosefZ The first key has a name-value pair of name:Plane2  value:SimSun-ExtB  The second key has the same.. But looking at that font, it doesn't have many characters in it

Comment: seems the topic is font substitution / font fallback.. this link asks a similar  question though not of notepad.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.os.windows-xp/cq-WLymBqhk  he doesn't get an exact answer but maybe there's more chance of an exact answer with a program as widespread as notepad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 7 has a technology called **composite font**

> that is used to describe international font linking and fallback logic   <sup>[source](http://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/windows-7-font-handling)</sup>

It allows you to have a virtual font linked from many fonts with limited ranges of character definitions.

Default composite font is called **GlobalUserInterface** and is located in file
`C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont`.

You can use great [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) tool to play around and understand implementation of Unicode, Composite fonts and related things.

Also check **Font Fallback** subsection of **Remarks** section of this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn some interesting background how such a composite font is built and what are fallback rules.

---

Finding a font for character (based on the above information):

1. In any plain text editor/viewer, display the file
   `C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont`.
2. In tag `<FontFamily.FamilyMaps>`, find definition range for your character.
3. Search for tag `FontFamilyMap` containing your range in its `Unicode` attribute and get font (or list of fonts) given for that range (it is stored in attribute `Target`).
   **Example:** in case of character **05D0** the range found in file is **0590-05FF** (Hebrew)
   and font substitutions are:
   `"Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"`

   4. If there was only single font, you have it. Otherwise, let's check the list in order: run BabelMap
   5. Navigate to given character
   6. Switch radio buttons from **Composite Font** to **Single Font**
      or alternatively: go to menu **Fonts** > **Font Coverage...** and press **Calculate** button
   7. Switch to fonts in order as they appear in step **3**. First font having the glyph displayed is your font.

**Note:** there are 4 composite font files available, but I verified the right one for your case is `GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont`.

*This technique is reliable because by searching through the definitions you are doing the same as the Windows is doing.*

Comment: That does not tell me what font is used to display a particular character, when notepad claims it's lucida console when it isn't lucida console.  If you're just saying it uses a composite of fonts and not lucida for that one, then i'm asking what font, how I can determine what font.   You're not really adding much here. I know already it's not lucida console, I know that abcdefg may well be in lucida console. My whole question is what font is it, and how can I determine that

Comment: @barlop – see updated answer for steps

Comment: That is amazing, thanks.. One other thing..  If I choose lucida and make font size 72, vs choosing segoe ui and making font size 72, the font size is different.. Any idea how it is making that font size choice?

Comment: @barlop  – yes I see that. I guess that it is taking line height of current font (Lucida, Segoe UI) and then, if it finds that Tahoma (containing Aleph glyph) is smaller, it scales it up (maybe eventually also down, if needed?) to match line height of selected font. I did not test it extensively, but this is how it looks  to me. You can also back up your composite font file and try changing value of `Scale` attribute of `FontFamilyMap` tag in your character range and see what it does (maybe it requires PC restart). Maybe also the above resources could reveal some explanation on how it works.

Comment: You write "  there are 4 composite font files available I verified the right one for your case is GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont." <-- how did you verify that?

Comment: @barlop – check other 3 fonts. Based on fonts contained in their `FontFamilyMap` attribute for Hebrew you can clearly see they have different purpose. For example, Monospace composite font links Hebrew to Courier New font, you will soon understand that the whole thing is for scenarios where an app requests for special typewriter-like fonts, having all characters of the same width. Similar case is with other composite fonts. Do you think you can check them yourself? But the main proof was that only the GlobalUI font was actually leading to the font with corresponding Aleph character in Notepad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26608/discussion-between-barlop-and-miroxlav).

Comment: i'm not sure if the chat will stay up 'cos it has less than 15 messages..  As the rule says  http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention   "Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface."  So who knows it it may suddenly be deleted.. i'll link to a copy of it here http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yudakKiW

Comment: also I didn't get your latest msg 'cos you didn't do @ before my name.. But, I see Segoe UI doesn't have Aleph..  i'm on Windows 7..  I see Tahoma has aleph.. So I guess notepad is getting it from there

Comment: also I didn't get your latest msg 'cos you didn't do @ before my name.. But, I see Segoe UI doesn't have Aleph..(I erred where I said it does). i'm on Windows 7.. I see Tahoma has aleph.. So I guess notepad is getting it from there  The first font listed in the composite font, that has the glyph.

Answer (score 2):

miro's answer is brilliant, i'm just going to write it slightly differently

There are a four composite font files.

The four are

```
C:\Windows\Fonts>dir *composite* /s/b

C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont
C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalSansSerif.CompositeFont
C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalSerif.CompositeFont
C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont

C:\Windows\Fonts>
```

Looking at them once sees that, for example,  `GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont` has 0590-06FF  and the fallback fonts listed, just one, is Courier New, which has Aleph. But Miro determined that that's not the composite file used, and that the one used is `GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont`

Open this file  `C:\Windows\Fonts\GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont`

Aleph is `\u05D0` so you have to scroll the file down to get to where i'm showing in the pic, but that's the section to look at

The composite font file lists a family of fonts to act as fallback fonts for various ranges of unicode characters, including  `0590-06FF` (which is the range that includes 05D0/aleph)

```
    <FontFamilyMap  
        Unicode          = "0000-052F, 0590-06FF, 0750-077F, 1D00-1FFF, 2C60-2C7F, FB00-FB0F, FB1D-FBFF" 
        Target           = "Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Arial Unicode MS, Microsoft Sans Serif, Lucida Sans Unicode"
        Scale            = "1.0"/>
```

[image]

Charmap can reach as far as FFFF which is far enough.  Charmap show that it's not in segoeUI.  But it is in Tahoma.

[image]

Babelmap is interesting because it can show characters past FFFF (not necessary in this case), and also it can show what fonts on your system have a particular unicode character.  But to see what font is actually used in practice by notepad, as a fallback font, you need to check that GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont file.  Then look in charmap or babelmap for the first font with the glyph/unicode character that you want.

Babelmap has composite fonts but I think they are custom ones not specifically the custom one used by windows.  But one could usefully use babelmap to search for which font has a unicode character, or to look at what characters are within a font, even beyond FFFF.